# Stop DOMXPath evaluate from converting special characters

Tags: php, html

If you run this DOMXPath evaluate on a url with special characters (I realize not technically valid url, but some websites have them anyway):

```
$a = '<a href="http://example.org/diseño"></a>';
$path = new DOMXPath( @DOMDocument::loadHTML( $a ) );
$href = $path->evaluate( 'string(//a/@href)' );

var_dump( $href );
// http://example.org/diseÃ±o
```

Is there a way to get a string with the "correct" href - as in with the special character?

```
http://example.org/diseño
```

Or is DOMXPath actually working properly because urls can't have special characters? If so, what's the cleanest alternative to get href from a string that includes special characters?

Comment: You could try `echo utf8_decode($href);`

Comment: Ah fantastic that worked, please add an answer with that and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just encode the return value from XPath...

```
echo utf8_decode($href);
```

which gives...

```
http://example.org/diseño
```